# Test for impulse response with vector autoregression in R

Tags: r, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I did a lot of VAR modeling in R using the VAR functions, then, I wanted to do impulse response testing.

My professor used the SVAR function, which I understand is for structured vector autoregressions (which have different underlying assumptions).  Is there a way to do impulse response testing and make it clear that I'm doing it in a VAR environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do impulse-response analysis (rather than testing, as you refer to it) of a VAR model using the `irf` function from the "vars" package in R. The functions takes an estimated VAR model -- an object of class `varest`. This is described in Section 3.4 of the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf).